# Are "how does x foreshadow Christ?" questions okay, and how to group them together?

Tags: discussion, scope, tag-wiki, community-wiki

So, I was thinking about asking (and answering some of) a series of questions titled "How does Character X typify Christ?" or "How does Scenario Y foreshadow Christ's work?". For example, after hearing a sermon on 2 Samuel 18, I wanted to ask "How does Absalom's Rebellion and David's behavior foreshadow Christ and his Work?"

First: is this format of question okay? [This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6975/how-does-the-passover-feast-foreshadow-the-coming-of-jesus-as-the-messiah) was asked and evidently is acceptable, so i'm guessing yes, as long as i'm not too broad and generic.

Second: Since I'd like to ask a series of questions, it'd be nice to have some sort of starting place or grouping point for them. Assuming it's a go-ahead on that question format, where should I group the questions together? They could go in the tag wiki, I suppose, which no one reads. Or, would a community wiki question (titled, for example, "how does david's life foreshadow Christ?") with links to all the specific questions be okay? And if we did do the community wiki, should all the specific questions be community wiki too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are OK. Just don't flood them all in at once, space them out over time. As to your two other questions:

1. The format is fine, I think, but you do need to give some context and tag them appropriately (christology, typology would be two good tags).
2. If you want to group them there are a couple of options here, CW is not one of them (Death to Community Wiki). The tag wiki for christology or typology might be good places to gather them, especially if they are good examples. OR if you are consistent with your tagging then they should be together if you click on the tag. This would be how I'd start.

Comment: okay, thanks. You make a good point about not flooding them in and also the tagging and automatic grouping. that's what i'll do! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'd say it's definitely OK.  From a Catholic perspective, we believe that Christ is written about in every part of the OT.  Figuring out where, how and why isn't necessarily easy. But [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=cZ5aYoSr3Hg) is a good start.